# How can I retrieve information from a file.txt after adding it before turning off the program

Tags: python, class, archive

I am learning to generate .txt files and how to write and read them, the problem I have now is that I want to make a program in which I can create, edit, and delete characters that appear similar to a table and that these new characters are saved in the file.txt

Seeing that the characters had attributes in common, I thought about using classes, I'm not really an expert in that, but I know a little, my main idea was to ask for the attributes and to generate an object and add it to a list of characters, doing it that way everything is fine but the data is not saved when you start the program again

```
class PLAYER:
    def __init__(self,Name,Attack,Defense,Health):
        self.Name=Name
        self.Attack=Attack
        self.Defense=Defense
        self.Health=Health

options=[0,1,2,3]
characters=[]

while True:
    counter=0
    archive = open("players.txt","w")
    print("ID|NAME|ATTACK|DEFENSE|HEALTH")
    while counter != len(characters):
        print("(",counter,")", characters[0+counter].Name,characters[0+counter].Attack,characters[0+counter].Defense,characters[0+counter].Health)
        counter += 1
    print("Character Manager")
    print("( 0 ) Create")
    print("( 1 ) Edit")
    print("( 2 ) Delete")
    print("( 3 ) Exit")
    while True:#Choose the option
        try:
            option=int(input("-> "))
            while option not in options:
                print("Are you looking to find more options? Sorry, friend, there is no budget for that")
                option=int(input("-> "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please write the number in parentheses of the option you want to do")
        
    if option==3:#Exit
        archive.close()
        break
    elif option==0:#Crear
        NAME=input("What will his name be? ")
        while True:#Ataque
            try:
                ATTACK=int(input("How much attack will it have? "))
                break
            except:
                print("please put an integer value")
        while True:#Defensa
            try:
                DEFENSE=input("How much will your defense be? ")
                break
            except:
                print("please put an integer value")
        while True:#Vida
            try:
                HEALTH=input("How much life will it have?")
                break
            except:
                print("please put an integer value")
        characters.append(PLAYER(NAME,ATTACK,DEFENSE,HEALTH))
    elif option==1:#Edit
        print("Which character do you want to edit?")
        ID=int(input("-> "))
        characters.remove(characters[ID])
        NAME=input("What will be his new name? ")
        while True:#Ataque
            try:
                ATTACK=int(input("How much attack will it have? "))
                break
            except:
                print("please put an integer value")
        while True:#Defensa
            try:
                DEFENSE=input("How much will your defense be?")
                break
            except:
                print("please put an integer value")
        while True:#Vida
            try:
                HEALTH=input("How much life will it have?")
                break
            except:
                print("please put an integer value") 
        characters.append(PLAYER(NAME,ATTACK,DEFENSE,HEALTH))
    elif option==2:#Delete
        print("¿Qué personaje quieres eliminar?")
        ID=int(input("-> "))
        characters.remove(characters[ID])
```

Up to this point I had not used the .txt file, so as not to show the complete code again I will only put the parts that change

```
    counter=0
    archive = open("players.txt","w")
    print("ID|NAME|ATTACK|DEFENSE|HEALTH")
    while counter != len(characters):
        a=("(",counter,")", characters[0+counter].Name,characters[0+counter].Attack,characters[0+counter].Defense,characters[0+counter].Health)
        archive.write(a)
        archive.write("\n")
        counter += 1
    archive.close()
    archive = open("personajes.txt","r")
    print(archive.read())
    print("Character Manager")
    print("( 0 ) Create")
    print("( 1 ) Edit")
    print("( 2 ) Delete")
    print("( 3 ) Exit")
```

The problem I found here is that the write argument must be str, not tuple but when putting

```
a = str ("all the stuff")
```

It appears to me

```
TypeError: str() takes at most 3 arguments (7 given)
```

So for now I run out of ideas to find a way to solve it, I hope you can help me to solve this since I couldn't find the solution on my own

an example of what I'm looking for is like this

```
ID|NAME|ATTACK|DEFENSE|HEALTH
Character Manager
( 0 ) Create
( 1 ) Edit
( 2 ) Delete
( 3 ) Exit

-> 0

What will his name be? Joseph

How much attack will it have? 20

How much will your defense be? 10

How much life will it have?50
ID|NAME|ATTACK|DEFENSE|HEALTH
( 0 ) Joseph 20 10 50
Character Manager
( 0 ) Create
( 1 ) Edit
( 2 ) Delete
( 3 ) Exit
```

but I want that when I start, old registered characters appear if there are

If I use an f-string

```
    counter=0
    archive = open("players.txt","w")
    print("ID|NAME|ATTACK|DEFENSE|HEALTH")
    while counter != len(characters):
        a=f"( {counter} ) {characters[counter].Name} {characters[counter].Attack} {characters[counter].Defense} {characters[counter].Health}"
        archive.write(a)
        archive.write("\n")
        counter += 1
    archive.close()
    archive = open("personajes.txt","r")
    print(archive.read())
```

The new characters are printed but at the moment of closing the program and reopening the characters that where created before disappear

Comment: Can you show an example input and the output you are looking for

Comment: You could have the class override [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). Or use an f-string: `a=f"( {counter} ),{characters[counter].Name} {characters[counter].Attack} {characters[counter].Defense} {characters[counter].Health}"`

Comment: I just edited the question to show the kind of output I'm looking for

Comment: Using an f-string the new characters are printed but at the time of closing the program and reopening it no character appears

Comment: Use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to store (serialize) objects to disk an retrieve (deserialize) them.

Comment: Could you explain me in an answer? I have never do that before

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to store and retrieve objects to disk. Here is an example based off your code:

```
import pickle

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, attack, defense, health):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.health = health
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.attack} {self.defense} {self.health}"

# Create 2 objects and save
def create_and_save():
    p1 = Player("name1", 1, 2, 3)
    p2 = Player("name2", 4, 5, 6)
    with open("players.bin", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(p1, f)
        pickle.dump(p2, f)

# Load the previously store object and print them
def load_data():
    with open("players.bin", "rb") as f:
        p1 = pickle.load(f)
        p2 = pickle.load(f)
    print(p1)
    print(p2)

choice = int(input("1. Save, 2. Load: "))
if choice == 1:
    create_and_save()
else:
    load_data()
```

Run the program twice. First time enter "1" and 2nd time enter "2".

<sup>P.S. I have modified the class member names to fit the [pep guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

use list comprehension to create all the lines as strings and then use join to join them all with \n

```
info = '\n'.join([list comprehension here])
file.write(info)
```